# Помещение блоков в массив и прокручивание их по нажатию "Previous" || "Next"

Tags: jquery

Создал вот такой код:

```
 var blocks[3] = ['#about', '#sunday_service', '#youth_service', '#childrens_service'];
 var currentDiv = 0;

 $('#next').click(function(){
if(currentDiv!=blocks.length-1){
       currentDiv++;

 $("#part_2").fadeToggle(300);
setTimeout(function(){ 
       $("#part_2").attr("id",blocks[currentDiv]);},300)
```

Вот дальше не знаю как продолжить. С картинками знаю как, там в

```
 attr("src", "blocks[currentDiv]);
```

А как в случае блока с ID?

Answer (score 1):

1. Для всех блоков в css: div { display:none;} или через скрипт сказать $(нужные).hide()
2. В зависимости от индекса в массиве - гасить,например, $('div#about').hide(), предыдущий и показывать нужный $('div#sunday_service').show() блок.

Идея понятна?

Comment: идея понятная, но не желанная. Я хочу создать слайдер "вправо - влево" переходили

Comment: Берем и нужный контейнер перемещаем (хоть весь, хоть отдельную инфу) в слайдер. ID нужного контейнера известно...